# JSF - Trouble With panelGrid and rendered

Tags: jsf

Hi in my code i had one panelGrid that have my calendar and another panelGrid that have my dataTable, my panelGrid/dataTable (id= display 3) only gonna appears if my list isn't null, but it only works if i had the panel display

```
<p:panel id="display" visible="false" header="Dia Selecionado #{cd.getdF()}" />
```

If I take it off my `display3` stop to work. Why is this happening?

```html
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <p:calendar value="#{cd.date1}" pattern="dd/MM" locale="pt" mode="inline">     
            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{cd.updateDate}" update="@form"/>
        </p:calendar>
        <p:panel id="display" visible="false" header="Dia Selecionado #{cd.getdF()}" />
        <p:outputPanel id="gridContainer" layout="block" >
            <h:panelGrid id="display3" rendered="#{cd.lista.size()>0}" columns="2" >

                <p:panel id="display21" header="Dia Selecionado #{cd.getdF()}" style="width:250px; text-align: center">  
                    <p:dataTable var="d" value="#{cd.lista}" emptyMessage="Não há compromissos para o dia." >  
                        <p:column headerText="00:00" >  
                            <h:outputText value="#{d.hr0}" />  
                        </p:column>  
                    </p:dataTable>  
                </p:panel>
                <p:panel id="display1" visible="false" header="Dia Selecionado #{cd.getdF()}" />
                <p:panel id="display22" header="Dia Selecionado #{cd.getdF()}" style="width:250px; text-align: center">  
                    <p:dataTable var="d" value="#{cd.lista}" emptyMessage="Não há compromissos para o dia.">  
                        <p:column headerText="13:00" >  
                            <h:outputText value="#{d.hr13}" />  
                        </p:column>  
                    </p:dataTable>
                </p:panel>

            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Can you state your problem and setup clearer?

Comment: Try to keep <p:panel id="display" visible="false" header="Dia Selecionado #{cd.getdF()}" /> as it is and just set the header value from "Dia Selecionado #{cd.getdF()}" to "Dia Selecionado". And you will find it will stop working. So As per my observation the list is setting in calling #{cd.getdF()} method.